# Modular dependency registration in Aurelia

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, aurelia

I am building an Aurelia web application using **TypeScript** with modularization in mind. What I mean by that is that every part of the application should be independent so that maintenance will be easier in the future.

What causes me a headache for the last few days is that I cannot figure out how I can register **my dependencies in a (more) modular way**. What I mean by that can most easily be illustrated using code.

For example, I have the following interface in my application:

```
export interface HeaderItem {
    name: string;
    url: string;
}
```

Implementations of this interface show up in the top most navigation section of my application. The idea is that if a new top-level section should be added a developer just implements the `HeaderItem` interface and registers the implementation to the container.

The code of my navigation component makes use of the `@all` injection and looks like this:

```
export class Header {
  headerItems: any[] = [];

  constructor(@all('HeaderItem') private _headerItems : any[]){
    this.headerItems = _headerItems;
  }
}
```

So every type registered with the `HeaderItem` key will be resolved from the container.

What bothers me is that **every implementation of the interface has to be registered in the `main.ts` file** like this:

```
aurelia.container.registerSingleton('HeaderItem', BatchHeaderItem);
```

I do not like that. What I am looking for is a way that **every module can register its dependencies**. I would be okay just to register that `ModuleConfiguration` class in the `main.ts` file.

However, what I tried so far is that I created a `Module` interface and implemented it for the modules I have. Then I tried to create an instance using `new` in the configure method which resulted in an **entirely white screen**. I do not know why this is happening?!

What I also tried is that I registered the `Module` implementations with the container and resolved it in the configure method and then tried to call a method on it which of course, also did not work as expected.

**Do you know of a better way to separate the registration of components using the built-in Aurelia dependency injection mechanism to fit a more modular approach?**

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to inject Aurelia itself and register your modules, services like this?

```
import { autoinject } from 'aurelia-framework'
import { Aurelia } from 'aurelia-framework'

@autoinject()
export class MyModule {
  constructor(
    private aurelia: Aurelia
  ) {
    this.init();
  }

  private init(){
    this.aurelia.container.registerSingleton(...register what you want...);
  }
}
```

Comment: How can the MyModule class be registered or called itself? As I mentioned in my question the root of the problem is that I cannot instantiate and call a component that registers something while startup. The screen remains white. Nothing in console.

Comment: You could import and write `aurelia.container.get(MyModule);` in main.ts to autoregister your module.Create a little repo and we can work on this together.

Comment: This information could be also very helpful => https://github.com/dryajov/aurelia-factory-methods